# How to assign same key to all value in list in python3

Tags: python-3.6

I have two lists with the same length one contains integer values and another string.
`a = [4, 8, 13, 24, 35, 56]
    b = ['acb','cde','efg','hij','klm','nop']`

I want to make dictionary like this:`dictionary = {{'number':4,'name':'abc'}, {'number':8,'name':'cde'}, {'number':13,'name':'efg'}, {'number':24,'name':'hij'}, {'number':35,'name':'klm'}, {'number':56,'name':'nop'}}`

  the key should be the same for all the value. Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the method you want, please check the following.

```
a = [4, 8, 13, 24, 35, 56]
b = ['acb','cde','efg','hij','klm','nop']

c = zip(a,b)
final_dic = dict()
for i,a in enumerate(c):
    temp=dict(number=a[0],name=a[1])
    final_dic[i]=temp
print(final_dic)
```

Since the output need to be dictionary format, so I just add the number as the key value.
I'm also new to Python, so there might be a better to do this.